# airbrake don't working by Rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, airbrake

ENV

- Rails 3.2.13
- ruby 1.9.3p392
- airbrake 3.1.11
- rake, version 10.0.4

my config file and rake task file

```
#lib/tasks/raise.rake
namespace :raise do
  desc "raise sth"
    task :sth => :environment do
      num = 1 / 0 # should raise error
    end
  end
end

# config/initializers/airbrake.rb
Airbrake.configure do |config|
  config.rescue_rake_exceptions = true
  config.api_key = Setting.airbrake_api
end
```

I hope run `RAILS_ENV=production rake raise:sth` send message to my airbrake, but nothing happen, just output `divided by 0`, not anything call stack info.

please help me, thank you ~

Comment: try downgrading to airbrake 3.0..9 and see what happens